# How to chose between types, classes, function types in TypeScript in this case?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am writing a small todo cli utility, the entire program is on the screen below - it is very simple and straightforward. There is a main file where arguments passed on the command line are parsed, and there are actions (add a task, delete a task, etc.). Depending on the arguments passed, certain actions are called. Each action is just a function which writes / deletes data from json file. Initially, the program was written in JS, and now i decided to translate it into TS. Question: how to determine what is more suitable for actions in this case: make them classes, describe types alias for them, or describe functional types for them, or maybe interfaces? Or put all actions just in one class? The project itself:

[image]

Comment: If you are writing nice functional code today, I would stick to that in Typescript.

Comment: so you mean functional interfaces?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with functional interfaces. You'll want to make a `type` for the the argument to the action()` function.

Comment: sorry i meant function types - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#function-types

Comment: Typescript is a typing system around JS, so everything you can do in JS can also be correctly described as Typescript types. Just as you can write the code in multiple ways in JS, you can choose multiple ways to type exactly the same thing.

Comment: thx i'm just new to TypeScript honestly. Just trying too work with TypeScript, getting familiar with it's features. Maybe i'm overengineering thing a bit =)

Comment: What you wrote in JS is good. Keep that, but add types. Don't redesign the API unless you have a good reason to.

Comment: Please do not post screenhots of code but insert it as text (there is a button for formatting it as code).

Answer (score 0):

So i as @Evert suggested i'm gonna declare types for functions